# How can we use inheritance with the module system?

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I have a single module and two classes:

```
module OpenORPG {

    export class MovementSystem extends GameSystem {
}

}


module OpenORPG {

    export class GameSystem {

        public parent: Zone;

}

}
```

They look something like that. This gets an error, as described in this issue: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/627

This happens with modules, though. Can anyone comment on how getting these types of depedencies works? I just get a dreaded:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even within the module you need to order the two properly i.e.

```
module OpenORPG {
    export class GameSystem {
        public parent: Zone;
    }
}

module OpenORPG {
    export class MovementSystem extends GameSystem {
}
```

**Update:** If you have this split in seperate file you can order the code generated from `--out` using a `reference` file that lists the files in order.

PS: grunt-ts can generate a reference file for you https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Comment: My module is composed of these two in separate files. That's the dillema.